# VMware player 17.0.2 - Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (kernel 5.19.0-46-generic)

vmplayer 17.0.2

error at startup VM:  "Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory."

> sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
>
> Starting VMware services:
> Virtual machine monitor                                            > failed
> Virtual machine communication interface                             > done
> VM communication interface socket family                            > done
> Virtual ethernet                                                   > failed
> VMware Authentication Daemon                                        > done
> Unable to start services

solution:
1.Disable secure boot via BIOS
2.run "sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all"

Comment: I'm having the same problem or close relative.  After following the directions to sign all my VMware drivers, my error is 
sudo modprobe vmnet
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vmnet': Key was rejected by service

From lots of reading, it seems this may be a problem with the DKMS signing system used to authenticate drivers.  Please update your answer with the output from this command:
uname -a
Linux developer1 5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

To see if you have the same kernel I do.

Comment: @karel That is exactly the process I followed to sign my drivers.  No change.  As I said, it seems to be a problem with the 5.19.0-46 kernel.